# PHP Defining $varname changes $_SESSION['varname']

Tags: php, variables, session

It took me a while to realize that $_SESSION['user'] was changing because I have a variable set: $user = array();

Is this normal? I haven't had this issue until today, not sure if it is a server/php setting

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try turning off register_globals in your php.ini file.

Comment: Hmm, I don't know if I can since I am on shared hosting but after reading up on r.g. this is almost positively the answer. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Depends on how you set $_SESSION['user'].

If you are setting it by reference then it is tied to the variable you used to set it.

ie.

$_SESSION['user'] =& $user;

$user = array();

now $_SESSION['user'] is an empty array

Comment: No I never had that, my login process page set it as:
$_SESSION['user'] = $users_array['id'];

Although that is nice to know for the future